# How do go's len() and make() functions work?

Tags: function, types, go

How do go's `len()` and `make()` functions work? Since the language lacks support for both generics and function overloading I don't see how `func len(v Type) int` is possible. The same goes for `func make(Type, size IntegerType) Type`.

I can't seem to find the function in the go source, the closest I've managed to find is [this](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `len` and `make` functions are part of the language specification and built-in to the compiler. Runtime support for built-in functions is in the [runtime package](http://golang.org/src/runtime/).

The file [builtin.go](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go) is used for documentation only. It's not compiled.

Comment: More than it being part of the compiler: it's hard-coded in as part of the language specification.  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels

Comment: len is also the only "function" capable of returning a const (when used on arrays). The spec gives built-ins special powers we mere mortal programmers cannot match.

Comment: Is there a link to the exact place where `len` is actually implemented?

Comment: @CeriseLimón In 2024 (or earlier), `reflect.SliceHeader()` is *Deprecated: Use [`unsafe.Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Slice) or [`unsafe.SliceData`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#SliceData) instead.*

Answer (score 1):

Because of Go's strict types, the compiler always knows what type you are passing to the `len` function and so it goes to a different function for different types, which can be determined at compile-time. In most cases you are attempting to get the length of a slice, in which case the `len` function only need return the `len` field for that slice's struct (since a slice is really a struct); same for a string.

Compilers have all kinds of tricks, the assembly code generated by the compiler rarely follows the exact same logic you typed.